# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when adding group fields in content type in Strapi

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, strapi

I am new to Strapi.  I have created a simple group field and was trying to add this field to the model "position". Before I added this field into the model, everything works perfectly. However, once I added in, when I go to the position page, it displays "an error occurred during models config fetch". When I try to add a document, it says " Cannot read property '0' of undefined". 
Does anyone know what;s happening and how should I fix it?

Thank you very much! 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jkb8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmkdD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjKcd.png)

Comment: Hello! Can you give me your Strapi version and the database you use.

Comment: Hi Jim! Thank you for helping me!  I was using 3.0.0-beta.17.1, the problem seems to be resolved when I upgrade it to 3.0.0-beta.17.5 :)

Comment: Cool perfect! Thank you for the feedback